# CSS issue with default button

Tags: css

How do I change link and background colours of `a.btn.btn-default` / `btn.btn-default`? I can’t find these in any CSS.

See here: https://www.webhosters.co.za/client/whois . There are two buttons at the bottom of the 404 error page. These buttons (home page and contact support) are in white text and white background. they are only visible when one hover over. How do I change the background and text?

Comment: The key is `:hover`. In your webpage, it's `.btn-default:hover` in
https://www.webhosters.co.za/client/templates/EcoHostingWP/css/all.min.css?v=808e87

Comment: added colour #6aaf08  as background on: .btn-default:hover{color:#333;background-color:#e6e6e6;border-color:#adadad}; .btn-default:hover{color:#333;background-color:#d4d4d4;border-color:#8c8c8c}; and .btn-default:hover{background-color:#fff;border-color:#ccc} . No changes were effected. Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small css snippet you can go through

```
section#main-body a.btn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6aaf08;
    border: 1px solid #6aaf08;
}
```

We are here inheriting button class Hope this helps

Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. Also tried to implement in custom .css and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can give class to that buttons and apply css on that like change in btn background and color

```css
.contact-btn, homepage-btn{
    background-color: #6aaf08 !important; 
    color: #fff !important;  

}
```

or

you can add more parents to .btn-default so your css will be applied first and will be replace .btn-default property

```css
#main-body .btn.btn-default {
    background-color: #6aaf08;
    color: #fff;
}
```

/* ------------------ or ------------ /*
 if you don't want to add parents class in css you need to  give important to that css property..

```
.btn.btn-default {
    background-color: #6aaf08 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Great place for styling links is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

so, basically you would be looking for something like:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: red;
  background-color: white
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: green;
  background-color: white
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
  background-color: white
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: blue;
  background-color: white
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. Also tried to implement in custom .css and it is not working.